# Applying a Handlebars template in JavaScript code

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Ember's Handlebars engine for a **not UI related** purpose. I have a series of text templates (basically placeholders + static text), like

```
Order number {{number}} / {{year}}
```

I'm using the following code in a controller function (simplified here for the sake of the example):

```
formattedTitle: function(order) {
   var orderTitle = "Order number {{number}} / {{year}}";
   var template = Handlebars.compile(orderTitle);
   return template(order);
}
```

`offer` is a Ember.data record, containing both fields.

When I run the function the resulting string only contains the static text:

> Order number /

It only works with the `{{id}}` property, probably because you can do `order.id` on the Ember.data record, but not  `order.number` (you have to use get - `order.get("number")`)

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Ember's `Object.getProperties()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_getProperties) to pull multiple properties into a simple javascript object and pass that in as the Handlebars context. Not sure that this is the best way to do this, though...

```
formattedTitle: function() {
    var order = Ember.Object.create({number: 1, year: 2013});
    // retrieve the properties ahead of time using Ember getter
    var orderContext = order.getProperties(['number', 'year']);
    var orderTitle = "Order number {{number}} / {{year}}";
    var template = Handlebars.compile(orderTitle);
    var output = template(order);
    return output;
}
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/372/edit)

Comment: Yes, that's a nice solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function formattedTitle(order) {
  var number = order.get('number');
  var year = order.get('year');
  var orderContext = { number: number, year: year };
  var orderTitle = "Order number {{number}} / {{year}}";
  var template = Handlebars.compile(orderTitle);
  var output = template(orderContext);

  return output;
}
```

Comment: I guess you forgot something. But I understand what you intended. Thanks.